# Uncaught Type Error : cannot read property NaN of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am making memory game, but I don't know why is JS throwing this error in setImg on line 48.

It looks like a issue with calling function nToYX() but i don't know what could be bad with it, it should only convert card number to y and x position. I am trying to fix it for a few days, but it's still not working.
EDIT:
Sorry, I messed up line 52, bad order of arguments. But i still don't know why
it's NaN.

```js
var Field = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

function ri(h) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(h));

}
for (i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
  while (true) {
    var x = ri(8);
    var y = ri(4);
    if (Field[y][x] == 0) {
      break
    }
  }
  Field[y][x] = i;


}

for (i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
  while (true) {
    var x = ri(8);
    var y = ri(4);
    if (Field[y][x] == 0) {
      break
    }
  }
  Field[y][x] = i;
}

var columns = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

function nToYX(num) {
  var ry = Math.round(num / 8);
  var rx = num % 8;
  return [ry, rx]
}

function setImg(blah, obj) {
  var r = nToYX(blah)[0];
  var c = nToYX(blah)[1];
  obj.innerHTML = '<img src="pics/uhol' + Field[r][c].toString() + '" style="{display:"none"}"/>';
}

for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) {

  setImg(columns[i], i);
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to provide  a [mcve]

Comment: You can get images from lorem kitten or placeholder.com

Comment: you are passing down column[i] (which is a DOM element) to setImg. then you are calling nToYX with it. this makes no sense... looks like you mixed up the order in which you should pass the arguments to setImg

Comment: It's very unclear what you're doing here `setImg(columns[i], i);`. Can you provide the html as well?

Comment: "TypeError: cannot read property ***NaN*** of ***undefined***" suggests that your code has multiple problems.

Comment: Oh, I already see it there:NToYX returned NaN and then I indexed `Field` with it and NaN can not be used as index. I was only a bit puzzled because of unclear error mesage.